# Changes to the javascript file are not reflected

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I'm making an interactive decision flow chart that uses svg.js. I'm working from [this example](https://github.com/rtalbot89/flow-svg).

I'm editing the `flowsvg.js` file that I've linked to my HTML file. Nothing happens when I make changes to the `.js` file, but if I delete the file the flow chart doesn't work. What might be causing this?

Comment: Either clear your cache (as per @Temidayo's answer), or append a unique value to your js file's querystring (e.g. flowsvg.js?v=1) to avoid caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which browser you are using in google chrome ,
Try clearing cache by right clicking on the page -> Inspect Element -> The right click the reload button and select Hard Reload.
Alternatively CTRL+Shift+I then clear cache